# create emf generated model from an uml model

Tags: uml, emf, eclipse-gmf, papyrus

I'm triying to create a graphical editor using eclipse gmf, based on an uml model,

for this I created a .gnemodel file based on my uml model but I do not have the associations in the generated .ecore file

I used eclipse papyrus to create the uml model and I think there is something missing so the associations can be imported to the ecore file.

**Edit** (Image from comment)
[image]

Comment: Why do you think there's something missing?

Comment: i could not add a picture of the model explorer but there is properties of each class and I think the association should be expressed by a property or something like that, when i add an association there is nothing added to the class to indicated that this class has an association

Comment: If you place the picture on a public server and post the link someone can add it to your question

Comment: here is the link 
http://imgur.com/U5ALtl0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, actually in this example the association owns both 
of its ends so changing the owner of the end i want to use in my .ecore file into classifier in the properties view of papyrus worked.
This is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUccb.jpg